# How can we have different speeds relative to a same point for a same object?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, relativity, earth, time-dilation

A day last not the same at all altitudes (https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.5000802), meaning earth has different angular velocities.

What is the actual rotation speed of the earth to the nearest nanosecond?

How can we have different speeds relative to a same point for a same object?

Comment: We can't.  Your first sentence is incorrect.  From the abstract (article paywalled), I think you have not understood the point of the paper.  It is about gravitational time dilation not rotation speed.

Comment: "A clock used to time a full rotation of the earth will measure the day to be approximately an extra 10 ns/day longer for every km of altitude above the reference geoid." in the article

Comment: It is the same as saying "earth rotates 10 ns/day slower for every km of altitude above the reference geoid relative to fixed stars"

Comment: No it is not the same.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the comments made I'm going to answer what should really have been a simple comment response.

The OP is correct in a specific sense.

It all depends on  who is measuring time and what they're comparing it with.

Gravitational time dilation is *very* real and the paper describes this quite well.

This comment is wrong :

> We can't. Your first sentence is incorrect. From the abstract (article paywalled), I think you have not understood the point of the paper. It is about gravitational time dilation not rotation speed.

The paper has an [Arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00171) so no paywall problem.

The measured length of day for an observer at one height will indeed by different than that measured by someone at a different height.

That is precisely what gravitational time dilation says.

It doesn't matter whether you mean "linear" speed ( i.e. $v=\frac{2\pi r} T$ ) or rotational speed ( $\omega=\frac{2\pi} T$ ).  These will be measured differently precisely because the period of ortation will be measured as different by these two different observers.

> How can we have different speeds relative to a same point for a same object?

Because in relativity how you move and where the observer is and the thing being measured are can be different and these differences affect the measured values compared to each other.

The object being measured is the same in this case, but you are comparing a measurement made by one observer (at one height) with another (at a different height).

> What is the actual rotation speed of the earth to the nearest nanosecond?

This is a sort of impossible to define well quantity.

Earth is not a convenient spherically symmetric sphere and so the gravitational field is not so conveniently handled as these formulas suggest.

Because Earth is more like an oblate spheroid there is no single spherical surface to use as a reference for length of day.  The period of rotation of Earth about it's own axis is also not a constant due to various other effects.  The solution to this problem is to *form a committee*. :-)

The official length of a day is a *human defined quantity*, not a measured one.  A committee "designed" the best compromise day length for various purposes and came up with :

> In 1967–68, during the 13th CGPM (Resolution 1), the International Bureau of Weights and Measures (BIPM) redefined a second as
>
> … the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom.
>
> This makes the SI-based day last exactly 794 243 384 928 000 of those periods.

Actually this is *two* committees' work. :-)

It will occur to you perhaps that this is very chicken-and-egg.  These units are human defined and not physically defined.   The definition of the second is designed to fit other criteria and the definition of a day (in SI units) kind of arbitrarily chosen to have a definition as much for legal purposes as any other.

The result of this is that a day is "legally" defined as 86400 seconds *exactly*.  The fact that this doesn't relate exactly to any specific astrophysical measurement is not relevant to the committee.  It's also why physicists use "seconds" (which are reasonably well defined in terms of a physical phenomenon) and not "days" which is a vague term useful for humans and lawyers.

Comment: Probably they (committees) set the day at 0m of altitude. But physically how can earth have different angular speeds (a geoid should rotate everywhere the same)? When I see a car I am sure of its speed relative to earth for every observer, why not in this case (relative to fixed stars)?

Comment: I think you need to get to grips with the basics of special relativity to get a feel for time dilation.  Again it's a case of who is doing the measurement and the rate time passes *for them*  compared to an observer at a different place undergoing different motion (and in general relativity, subject to different gravitational fields).  Note that understanding this does mean letting go of your "common sense" everyday understanding of time and space - it's hard to do.  The maths is important in getting an understanding.

Comment: *Probably they (committees) set the day at 0m of altitude.* This is a problem in it's own right.  Earth is not a sphere, so there is no single radius to define as a basis for a zero altitude.  And Earth's surface is not even a neat geometric shape - just defining a basis h=0 is tricky.